# reqex match string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have this text, inside another text:

```
[text_box title="Michael Jordan" align="left"] Basketballplayer ... 
[/text_box]
```

I have to match this text with reqex and replace it with:

```
<div class="text-box alignleft"> <h4>Michael Jordan</h4>
```

How can i match the textbox? Textboxes can appear more than once in my text, with different titles and aligns.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: That's not a search or replacement. You have a template that you want to fill. Regular expressions are *not* the best way to do that.

Comment: Interpretting this pseudocode as text and using regular expressions on it is almost certainly a bad idea in practice.  You probably need to have something a little more robust like a parser of some sort.

Comment: It's hard to come up with a useful regex because you ommit a LOT of critical information. For example, do you match tags with css classes, ie `text_box` with `text-box` ? Do you have a *mapping* from tags to classes? Where does `h4` come from? You'd have to create a regex that matches all tags and attributes, *and* include mappings from various tags to styles and HTML tags for this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/KxuAnW/1) if your textbox is allway structured like this:

```
\[text_box title="(.*?)" align="(.*?)"
```

Group one will be the titles content and group 2 the alignments content

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("\\[text_box title=\"(.*?)\" align=\"(.*?)\"");
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);

foreach(var match in matches)
{
   string title = match.Groups[1].Value;
   string alignment = match.Groups[2].Value;
   string output = string.Format("<div class=\"text-box align{1}"> <h4>{0}</h4>", title, alignment);
   // or in newer .Net Framework
   string output = $"<div class=\"text-box align{alignment}"> <h4>{title}</h4>";
}
```

Comment: Which won't produce any output. Parsing the template is only 1/4 of the job.

Comment: Perhaps if any code would be provided I could help to point it in the right direction. But there wasn't. Based on the regex the op could try something on his own and come back with a more specific set of questions. This is not a consulting site after all

Comment: For example, where do the styles come from? Should the regex recognize `text_box` and map it to `text-box`? What about the *replacement*?

Comment: "align" could be before title.  OP didn't specify so you shouldn't assume.  Also the inner text of the [text_box] tag could contain [text_box inside that shouldn't be parsed.  If that sounds difficult to take into consideration using a regular expression, it is because a regular expression is not the right approach here.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé you should have posted this as a comment then. This question is about replacement after all, not a simple search. You could have used named groups to make writing the replacement expression easier.

Comment: okay, nice thanks. Can I also group the text "Basketballplayer ... ", which always appear after the align="left"] tag?

Comment: @Mykremin try this regex `\[text_box title="(.*?)" align="(.*?)"](.*)\[`

Comment: @RomanoZumbé thank you :) if i have a newline on my text how can I also catch that? (.*) this one will not catch the match if I for example write
Michael \n
Jordan

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following snippet:

```
string input = "[text_box title=""Michael Jordan"" align=""left""] Basketballplayer[/text_box]";
string pattern = "\[text_box title=""([^""]+)"" align=""([^""]+)"".*";
string replacement = "<div class=""text-box align$2""> <h4>$1</h4></div>";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

To understand templates and substitutions you could see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx). It helps you to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm) tool to write and test regular expressions. It will generate C# code as well, see the below code block which generated using expresso.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

/// <summary>
///  Regular expression built for C# on: Mon, May 29, 2017, 02:24:58 PM
///  Using Expresso Version: 3.0.5854, http://www.ultrapico.com
///  
///  A description of the regular expression:
///  
///  \[text_box title="
///      Literal [
///      text_box
///      Space
///      title="
///  [title]: A named capture group. [.*?]
///      Any character, any number of repetitions, as few as possible
///  " align="
///      "
///      Space
///      align="
///  [align]: A named capture group. [.*?]
///      Any character, any number of repetitions, as few as possible
///  ".*\]
///      "
///      Any character, any number of repetitions
///      Literal ]
///  [data]: A named capture group. [.*]
///      Any character, any number of repetitions
///  \[\/text_box\]
///      Literal [
///      Literal /
///      text_box
///      Literal ]
///  
///
/// </summary>
public static Regex regex = new Regex(
      "\\[text_box title=\"(?<title>.*?)\" align=\"(?<align>.*?)\"."+
      "*\\](?<data>.*)\\[\\/text_box\\]",
    RegexOptions.Singleline
    | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
    | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );


// This is the replacement string
public static string regexReplace = 
      "<div class=\"text-box align${align}\"><h4>${title}</h4>";


//// Replace the matched text in the InputText using the replacement pattern
string result = regex.Replace(InputText,regexReplace);

//// Split the InputText wherever the regex matches
 string[] results = regex.Split(InputText);

//// Capture the first Match, if any, in the InputText
 Match m = regex.Match(InputText);

//// Capture all Matches in the InputText
 MatchCollection ms = regex.Matches(InputText);

//// Test to see if there is a match in the InputText
 bool IsMatch = regex.IsMatch(InputText);

//// Get the names of all the named and numbered capture groups
 string[] GroupNames = regex.GetGroupNames();

//// Get the numbers of all the named and numbered capture groups
 int[] GroupNumbers = regex.GetGroupNumbers();
```